# Use jQuery to determine if any subsequent elements have a particular data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a number of divs:

```
<div class="theoriginalthing"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div data-stuff="1" class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
```

I am trying to determine if any of the subsequent divs after .theoriginalthing have a data attribute called stuff that equals 1.

Here is what i have, but it returns NOPE each time.

```
if(jQuery('.theoriginalthing').nextAll('.thething').data('stuff') == '1') {

alert('FOUND ONE!');

} else {

alert('NOPE');

}
```

Here is my fiddle for this:

https://jsfiddle.net/xstatic/15zesd98/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple items in the `.nextAll` collection, so the `.data('stuff')` won't necessarily refer to the proper element.

You can select an element with a particular attribute and a particular value for that attribute in the selector string passed to `nextAll`:

```js
if (jQuery('.theoriginalthing').nextAll('.thething[data-stuff="1"]').length) {
  console.log('FOUND ONE!');
} else {
  console.log('NOPE');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theoriginalthing"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div data-stuff="1" class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each of them.

```js
found = false;
jQuery('.theoriginalthing').nextAll('.thething').each(function(){
    if($(this).data("stuff") != undefined){found = true}
})

console.log(found)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theoriginalthing"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div data-stuff="1" class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
```

Comment: `data-stuff="2"` would not be undefined, but is that found, by what the OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab this very element with a single CSS selector:

```css
.theoriginalthing ~ [data-stuff="1"]
```

The break up would be
`.theoriginalthing` - Element with class "theoriginalthing"
`~` look into siblings
`[data-stuff="1"]` for a an element with an attribute `data-stuff` that has a value equal to `"1"`

```js
$('.theoriginalthing ~ [data-stuff="1"]').addClass("found")
```

```css
.theoriginalthing,.thething { height: 15px; border: 1px solid; }
.found { background: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="theoriginalthing"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div class="thething"></div>
<div data-stuff="1" class="thething">find me</div>
<div class="thething"></div>
```